# Библиотека DND kit не работают кнопки

Tags: reactjs

Осваиваю DND kit, все работает но кнопки в карточке перестали реагировать на события.
Вот карточка

```
 <div className={classes.card} ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners}>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <img className={classes.remove} onClick={removeCard} src={remove} alt={remove}/>
            {tasks.map((item)=>
                <Task
                key={item.id}
                color={item.color}
                title={item.name}
                validDate={item.date}
                link={item.link}
                onRemove={()=>removeTask(item)}
                />)}
               
            <img className={classes.plus} src={plus} alt={'plus'} onClick={openTaskForm}/>
        </div>
```

А вот контекст

```
   <DndContext
            collisionDetection={closestCenter}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
        >
                <div className={classes.cardBlock}>
                    <SortableContext
                        items={_cardItemState}
                        strategy={horizontalListSortingStrategy}
                    >
                    {cards.map((item) =>
                        <Card key={item.id} id={item.id} card={item} taskKey={item.id} title={item.text}
                              tasks={item.tasks ? item.tasks : []}/>
                    )}
                    </SortableContext>
                </div>

        </DndContext>
```