# в библиотеке dnd kit для drag&drop при нажатии на вложенный компонент не срабатывает событие клика

Tags: reactjs, drag-n-drop

У меня два компонента, родительский и дочерний, брал пример из документации, в дочернем компоненте у меня реализована логика по событию onClick раскрывать список элементов внутри, а в родительском используется функция onDragEnd которая и осуществляет драгэнддроп, при перетаскивании все работает, но при нажатии список не раскрывается, понимаю что это связано с всплытием и погружением но пока не могу додуматься как это пофиксить, возможно свойство какое-то есть в этой библиотеке, которая позволяет осуществлять подобное?

если заменить onClick на onDoubleClick, то все будет работать, но к сожалению нужно реализовать именно при клике один раз

Родительский компонент:

```
const Tree = ({ className, data, onDataLoad, onTabOpen, selectedId }: TTreeProps) => {
        const [state, setState] = useState(data);
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            setState(data)
        },[data])
    
        //@ts-ignore
        const handleDragEnd = (e)=>{
            console.log('e handleDragEnd: ', e);
            const {active, over} = e;
            console.log("ACTIVE " + active.id);
            console.log("OVER " + over.id);
    
            if(active.id!==over.id){
                
                setState((cities) => {
                    const oldIndex = cities.findIndex((city) => city.id === active.id);
                    const newIndex = cities.findIndex((city) => city.id === over.id);
                    return arrayMove(cities, oldIndex, newIndex);
                });
            }
            
        };
    
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <TreeWrapper>
                <DndContext collisionDetection={closestCenter} onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
                    <SortableContext items={state} strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}>
                        {state.map((item) => (
                            <TreeNode
                                {...item}
                                key={item.id}
                                onDataLoad={onDataLoad}
                                onTabOpen={onTabOpen}
                                selectedId={selectedId}
                                isHeading={item.isHeading}
                            />
                            ))}
                    </SortableContext>
                </DndContext>
                </TreeWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default memo(Tree);
```

Дочерний компонент:

```
const TreeNode = ({
    title,
    children,
    disabled,
    isLeaf,
    onDataLoad,
    id,
    loadStatus,
    onTabOpen,
    selectedId,
    isHeading,
    open = false,
}: TTreeNodeProps) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [contentVisible, setContentVisible] = useState<boolean>(open);
    const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState<TLoadStatus | null>(loadStatus ?? null);

    const hasChildren = !!children?.length || !isLeaf;

    const {
        attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition
    } = useSortable({id:id});

    const style = {
        transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
        transition
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoadingStatus(loadStatus ?? null);
        if (loadStatus === LoadStatus.SUCCESS) {
            setContentVisible(true);
        }
    }, [loadStatus]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (open) setContentVisible(true);
    }, [open]);

    //@ts-ignore
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log('e handleClick: ', e);
        if (disabled) return;

        if (!isLeaf && !children && onDataLoad) {
            setLoadingStatus(LoadStatus.PROGRESS);
            onDataLoad(id);
        }
        if (hasChildren) {
            setContentVisible((prevState) => !prevState);
        }
        if (onTabOpen) {
            ref?.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "center" });
            onTabOpen(id);
        }
    };

    return (
        <NodeWrapper ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners}>
            <Heading $disabled={disabled} onClick={handleClick} $selected={selectedId === id} ref={ref}>
                {isHeading ? (
                    <TitleStyled tag="span" size="title24" $disabled={disabled}>
                        {title}
                    </TitleStyled>
                ) : (
                    <TextStyled tag="p" size="text16" $disabled={disabled}>
                        {title}
                    </TextStyled>
                )}
                {hasChildren && !isHeading && (
                    <>
                        {loadingStatus === LoadStatus.PROGRESS ? (
                            <LoaderStyled className="ml4" />
                        ) : (
                            <Arrow className="ml4" $open={contentVisible} />
                        )}
                    </>
                )}
            </Heading>
            {children && contentVisible && (
                <Tree
                    className="mt12"
                    data={children}
                    onDataLoad={onDataLoad}
                    onTabOpen={onTabOpen}
                    selectedId={selectedId}
                />
            )}
        </NodeWrapper>
    );
};

export default TreeNode;
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что клик не срабатывает и это именно из-за библиотеки? Если убрать обертку библиотеки, список начинает правильно работать?

Comment: @SwaD да, если убрать обертку, клик работает

Comment: Как полностью называется библиотека, которую используете?

Comment: @SwaD https://docs.dndkit.com/

Comment: уже кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой, но к сожалению ответа тоже не нашел
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527792/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-dnd-kit-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8